How to access Android API private methods?
I'm trying to access a private method of the TrafficStats class called nativeGetIfaceStat, which is public in API 31. I've attempted to do this using both Java and C++, but neither approach has worked.
Here's what I've tried:

Using Java:
public static long getIfaceStat(String iface, int type) {
    try {
        Method declaredMethod = TrafficStats.class.getDeclaredMethod("nativeGetIfaceStat", String.class, int.class);

        declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);

        return (long) declaredMethod.invoke(null, iface, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Net_Interface", e.toString());

        return -1; }
}

This approach throws a NoSuchMethodException.

Using C++:
extern "C"JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALLJava_com_example_getIfaceStat(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring iface, jint type) {
    jclass trafficStatsClass = env->FindClass("android/net/TrafficStats");

    if (trafficStatsClass == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    }

    jmethodID methodID = env->GetStaticMethodID(trafficStatsClass, "nativeGetIfaceStat", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)J"); 

    if (methodID == nullptr) {     return -1; 
    }

    jlong result = env->CallStaticLongMethod(trafficStatsClass, methodID, iface, type); 

    return result;
}

This approach blocks the running process.



Why do you think that method exists in the android.net.TrafficStats class?

Because it exists in class source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/16f1d81/core/java/android/net/TrafficStats.java

A method nativeGetIfaceStat() was added to TrafficStats on April 10, 2012 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/234766a36af6214644fa8205202287084ca9cf93%5E%21/#F2)
This method was later removed, on Nov 14, 2017 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/d3d9c4ed9baa97f70858e639a01345a3cd78f42d%5E%21/#F1)
Since this method doesn't exist anymore you cannot make it accessible.

It seems that in Android 12 it was still available (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r4/core/java/android/net/TrafficStats.java).
In Android 13 the class TrafficStats was removed from the framework core (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-platform-13.0.0_r23/core/java/android/net/) and moved to the Connectivity package (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Connectivity/+/refs/tags/android-platform-13.0.0_r23/framework-t/src/android/net/TrafficStats.java). Whatever nativeGetIfaceStat() did was solved there in some other way.

This is generally a problem when trying to access private methods: they are regarded as implementation details that can be freely renamed, moved to some other place or completly removed.

But why is it available in here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/16f1d81/core/java/android/net/TrafficStats.java

Ahom because in that included all methods available and removed actually the real one is here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-12.1.0_r4/core/java/android/net/TrafficStats.java thank very much

@MohammadAzizi I've updated my answer. Seems that in the official releases that private method was removed in Android 13.

public static String[] getMobileIfacesRelect() {
try {
Method declaredMethod = TrafficStats.class.getDeclaredMethod("getStatsService");
declaredMethod.setAccessible(true);
return (String[]) Class.forName("android.net.INetworkStatsService").getMethod("nativeGetIfaceStat").invoke(declaredMethod.invoke(null));
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
Log.d("Net_Interface", e.toString());
return new String[]{"not found"};
}
} Still throw not found exception

@MohammadAzizi sorry, from your code fragments I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe there is a better way to do whatever you want to do without accessing private internal details of some classes.

getStatsService is a private method that returns the INetworkstateservice object which contains nativeGetIfaceStat

@MohammadAzizi I understand that you desperately try to access a method that seems no longer available. What I do not understand: Why do you want to access that method? What feature are you trying to implement that you believe can only be implemented by accessing that method?

I want to Access that method because through that I can get transfered KB by specific interface name which is brings accuracy  and they brought that method in android 12 which is good and accurate but in lower android when we get transfered KB by gettotalTx that returns unaccurate kb which is counted x2,x3,x4 times when vpn,proxy connected
